# maven-release-plugin -D properties not accessible in the pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

When I perform release with maven-release-plugin I cannot get access to -Dusername and -Dpassword properties which used maven-release-plugin as scm username and password. How I can get access to this properties?
My release command:

```
mvn -B -f pom.xml -DdevelopmentVersion=2.5-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=2.4 -Dusername=ivan -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform -Dpassword=*********
```

Comment: You have <scm>..</scm> in your pom?

Comment: How it can affect on availability of property?

Comment: I can perform release but I can not write password and username to resorce file for example.